# JPDA JDI ObjectReference of java.io.InputStreamReader

Tags: java, debugging, jvmti, jpda, jdi

is there a way to retrieve String/Text from JPDA JDI `ObjectReference of java.io.InputStreamReader` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to read from it, you would have to advance through it, which would change the behaviour of the program being instrumented/debugged. I suggest *not* reading from it directly, but rather logging its reads, either using JDI or by modifying the calling code directly.

Comment: Do you mean from **logging its reads** ; `ObjectReference .invokeMethod "read"`

Comment: No, that invokes a read, which is exactly what I said _not_ to do.

Comment: So guide me briefly , what should i do to access text/string from reader by using JDI ?

Comment: Set breakpoints on all the read methods, and log what they return.

Comment: may you explain , why you not recommend to use ObjectReference.invokeMethod "read" ?

Comment: Because then the data gets read, and the programming being debugged doesn't see the data. So it goes wrong. It does the wrong thing. A debugger must not change the behaviour of a program under debugging. The only exception is if you are sure that you are going to immediately kill the program afterwards, then you can do whatever you like to its data.

Comment: Will Set breakpoints on all the read methods will best fit with my case scenario : On Client JVM InputStreamReader object is created and client use it to access data by read method after some step/time/event client notify me(Debugger JVM) to debug/analyze program and i need to access InputStreamReader text/string but after notifaction/event from client side ; there will be no call to read method from client side so will breakpoint will work on read method to access data because there will be no call  to read method after breakpoint set on read method .

Comment: Why will there be no call to read? If you want to know what it has read so far, surely it would be better to log the reads that the program *does* make? Rather than trying to figure that out from what is remaining in the InputStreamReader?

Comment: Got your point , May you help with some code snippet that will used to log method

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved, including attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me , may you provide some online resource for programming using JDI api for that task .

Comment: sorry I had a quick Google but I couldn't find anything